# access to object in service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Good day. There is an html page with connected script, from which I can get access to some object (e.g. `object`). In `index.js` file I can get access to this object. There is a function that takes `object` and return some data from it:

```
const getObject = () => {
  let data = object.data;
  return data;
}
```

If I call this function in `index.js` it works fine and I can get access to `object`. Also there is a service worker that connected to html page. Piece of code there:

```
self.addEventListner('message', event => {
   console.log('message' + event.data);
   importScripts('index.js');
   let data = getObject();
   console.log(data);
}
```

When I call `getObject` inside service worker I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined at self.addEventListener (sw.js:33)`. There is a question: how can i get access to `object` inside service worker?

Comment: here is an example https://codepen.io/serginij/project/editor/AekNyq

Comment: the const object is defined in module.js. try adding `importScripts('module.js');` in the service worker.

Comment: @J.Loscos your advice worked. But when I tried to do the same with other script I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Script error`. Don't you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The service worker and your controlled pages live in two completely different scopes, with their own set of symbols. It's not possible to refer to a function like `getObject()` directly across those two scopes.

It is, however, possible to use a helper library that will create a proxy between the two scopes, and basically "fake" a local interface that will actually call the remote method and communicate the result back asynchronously.

There are a few such libraries. One that I know works well for service worker communication is [Comlink](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink).

Here's an example, borrowed from Comlink's README:

```
// main.js
const MyClass = Comlink.proxy(new Worker('worker.js'));
// `instance` is an instance of `MyClass` that lives in the worker!
const instance = await new MyClass();
await instance.logSomething(); // logs “myValue = 42”

// worker.js
const myValue = 42;
class MyClass {
  logSomething() {
    console.log(`myValue = ${myValue}`);
  }
}
Comlink.expose(MyClass, self);
```

Comment: The example you shared is for worker. But the question is for Service Worker.